# Failed to install chrony in bootstrap node during DCOS installation on azure via Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, dcos

I am installing DC/OS on azure via terraform. My installation fails and I cannot get to the DC/OS dashboard due to this error.
The exact output is
**Error:module.dcos.module.dcos-core.module.dcos-install.null_resource.run_ansible_from_bootstrap_node_to_install_dcos (remote-exec):**

Terraform exits siting an error in the script that keeps changing. The latest output was:

**Error: error executing "/tmp/terraform_1565201352.sh": Process exited with status 2**

I creating a main.tf file as provide [here](https://docs.d2iq.com/mesosphere/dcos/2.2/installing/evaluation/universal-installer-0.3/azure/)

These outputs are after running **terraform apply "plan.out"** to execute the infrastructure plan.
What is causing this error & how can I resolve this?

Comment: Seems there is problem in the provided code which you are refering. You can refer this terraform official document [Creates a DC/OS Cluster on Azure](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/dcos-terraform/dcos/azurerm/latest)

Comment: does the above provided link works for you?

Comment: Nope it did not work: I am testing this one: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/dcos-terraform/infrastructure/azurerm/latest

Comment: Please update if does works for you.

Comment: This works. But Now I am not able to access the DCOS dashboard via the   module.infrastructure.lb_masters output variable